# Using SELECT inside COALESCE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

How do I correct the following SQL code, specifically the COALESCE part?

```
insert into Stmt G (ID,blah,foo)
select
coalesce(SELECT ID FROM Stmt G WHERE G.CLAIMNO=C.CLNUMBER, select StmtSeq.nextval from dual),
c.blah,
d.foo
from claim c
left join d on ...;
```

I'm taking the ID from the Stmt table itself if the ClaimNo matches, otherwise creating a new one. Is this not allowed in SQL? How else can I write this statement?

I'm getting a "Missing Expression" error on the coalesce part right now.

Comment: Which specific part of the query do you receive the error on?  (Paste the exact error message.)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You should place parenthesis around the `select`s:

```
coalesce( (SELECT ID FROM Stmt G WHERE G.CLAIMNO=C.CLNUMBER)
        , (select StmtSeq.nextval from dual)
        )
```

Comment: Please note, it's critical to have the space between the braces after coalesce.